# Create smallest grid in leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial, r-leaflet

I want to create **the smallest grid** as possible in leaflet R. How should I go about it ?

My current code is :-

```
leaflet()%>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = 101.9758, lat = 4.21053, zoom = 10)) %>%
  addGraticule(interval = 0.02, sphere = FALSE) %>%
  addMarkers(101.6995, 3.1473)
```

Here the picture output from the code before zoom
[image: Image before zoom in]

Here the picture after zoom in
[image: Image after zoom in]

The grid **quite large** after I zoom in but if I change **addGraticule(interval = 0.01)**, my **laptop hang** and **no output result**. I want the grid to be small as picture below

[image: Desired result]

Is there other way I can achieve my aim?

I found other function that might help which is

```
addSimpleGraticule(
  map,
  interval = 20,
  showOriginLabel = TRUE,
  redraw = "move",
  hidden = FALSE,
  zoomIntervals = list(),
  layerId = NULL,
  group = NULL
)
```

**zoomIntervals :- use different intervals in different zoom levels. If not specified, all zoom levels use value in interval option.**

But I'm not sure how to specify zoomIntervals arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Documentation of the R function `addSimpleGraticule` is not very verbose, but you can get a hint about the required data structure [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Graticule).

You can set the number of grid lines per meter depending on the zoom level indeed using the `zoomIntervals` option:

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = 101.6995, lat = 3.1473, zoom = 20) %>%
  addMarkers(101.6995, 3.1473) %>%
  addSimpleGraticule(
    showOriginLabel = TRUE,
    redraw = "move",
    hidden = FALSE,
    zoomIntervals = list(
      list(start = 1, end = 3, interval = 10),
      list(start = 4, end = 9, interval = 1),
      list(start = 10, end = 17, interval = 0.1),
      list(start = 18, end = 20, interval = 0.0002)
    ),
    layerId = NULL,
    group = NULL
  )
```

[image]
[image]
[image]